# How would you make a valid URL String when it contains &

Tags: html

Take this for example: `<a href="manageCart.php?action=remove&id=49">`

When validated, you will get this result:

`Line 26, Column 802: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)`

But this is not content, so the & is necessary. What is done to make it valid html?

Comment: just do what validator wants and do &amp; ???

Comment: Most web frameworks and libraries provide a means to Html encode pieces of text - but we can't provide examples without knowing how this HTML is being generated (e.g. which technologies are involved)

Comment: @ggzone - I was confused for a moment because since this would be in the URL I did not know that I can also use &amp; there

Comment: @Ryan yes you can :D and mark Josephs answer as accepted (check)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a href="manageCart.php?action=remove&amp;id=49">
```

Use `&amp;`

Comment: Ah so you still use the &amp; even though its in the url. Thanks mate, such as silly mistake from my end then.

Answer (score 0):

validaters usually want `&amp;` instead of just the `&` sign. when you click on the link it will still change it to `&` in the browsers url